# iOS - Crash with google admob SDK after upgraded to v7.7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

We upgraded google admob v7.5.1 to v7.7.0 through pod file. After upgrade app crash on launching with following log.

```
2016-03-21 12:17:47.065 myAppName[3672:83997] -[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0110632e20924c9
2016-03-21 12:17:47.119 myAppName[3672:83997] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0110632e20924c9'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3e8e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109e5fdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3f148d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a33e90a ___forwarding___ + 970
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a33e4b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a300e84 -[NSSet initWithArray:] + 36
6   myAppName                       0x000000010579e66e hasRequiredParams + 19102
7   myAppName                       0x000000010579c3a3 hasRequiredParams + 10195
8   myAppName                       0x000000010579c1fc hasRequiredParams + 9772
9   myAppName                       0x000000010579c048 hasRequiredParams + 9336
10  myAppName                       0x000000010573ad87 GADiTunesMetadataForFileAtPath + 2024
11  myAppName                       0x000000010573a7d2 GADiTunesMetadataForFileAtPath + 563
12  Foundation                          0x0000000106d07790 -[__NSObserver _doit:] + 304
13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3b569c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3b53db _CFXRegistrationPost + 427
15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3b5142 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3fa972 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1986
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a2b0279 _CFXNotificationPost + 633
18  Foundation                          0x0000000106ceb109 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
19  UIKit                               0x0000000107cb06f0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4272
20  UIKit                               0x0000000107cb6cc6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1760
21  UIKit                               0x0000000107cb3e7b -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
22  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bcdf754 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
23  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bcdfac2 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a314a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a30a95c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a309e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a309828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
28  UIKit                               0x0000000107cb37cd -[UIApplication _run] + 402
29  UIKit                               0x0000000107cb8610 UIApplicationMain + 171
30  myAppName                       0x00000001055b4c7e main + 62
31  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a8d492d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: I used Admob v7.7.0 but no crash. Did you add -ObjC linker flag ?

Comment: @NatureFriend Yes i added -ObjC linker flag

Comment: @Chandukumar.Alasyam found some solution on this? Have the same problem with one of my projects..

Comment: @Chandukumar.Alasyam some informations on this? Did you solved the issue?